# Power Bi help - Displaying values in cards with "conditions"

Tags: powerbi, conditional-statements

I have an issue with displaying cards in Power Bi which I can't seem to solve.

See, it's for a company I work with. They do different budget scenarios that they go adjusting as Actual expenditures incurr.

So, there's a slicer with "Budget 1 and Budget 2" as options (user can select only one option). The amount of income is shown for the Budget in a card and the Actual amount shown in another. Select 1 or 2, the amount is changed in the Budget card; Actual amount never changes as there is only one Actual.

But, they need to see the % difference from Actual and Budgeted.

So, user selects Budget 1, sees Budget 1 in Budget card, and Actual, I want him to see in a different card the % difference (Actual / Budget 1).
So, if user selects Budget 2, sees Budget 2 in Budget card (this is working perfectly), and Actual in Actual card,  I want him to see in a third card the % difference (Actual / Budget 2).

I created two different measures to calculate the % differences. One for each budget. However, having two cards makes no sense. Any way to turn around this one?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you would need to use a 3rd party visualization for this (or build your own)

This Advance Card visual may work for your scenario:

[image: Visual Store - Advance Card]

Comment: I tried this one before posting the question, couldn't seem to make it work... Any insights?

Comment: Try the infographic designer visual, you have the option of doing a card, and adding measure and layer to it. If you align the text right, it may do as you want it to do.